# Add object X to collection only if collection does not contain object with one matching property

Tags: java, collections, java-stream

I just started messing around with Java streams and I wrote something like this:

```
List<Device> devicesToDelete = new ArrayList<>();
List<Device> oldDeviceList = getCurrentDevices();

for (Device deviceFromOldList : oldDeviceList)
{
    // part to simplify

    boolean deviceNotExistOnDeleteList =
        devicesToDelete.stream().noneMatch(nd -> nd.id == deviceFromOldList.id);

    if (deviceNotExistOnDeleteList) {
        devicesToDelete.add(deviceFromOldList);
    }

    // part to simplify end
}
```

**Can it be simplified even more?**

*I'm not using Set because my `Device` class `.equals()` implementation compares all fields in that class. And here I need to compare only `id` field.*

Comment: "*I'm not using Set because my `Device` class `.equals()` implementation compares all fields in that class. And here I need to compare only `id` field.*" - [`TreeSet(Comparator<? super E>)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/TreeSet.html#%3Cinit%3E(java.util.Comparator))?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use a `Map`

```
Map<Object, Device> devicesToDelete = new HashMap<>();
List<Device> oldDeviceList = getCurrentDevices();

for(Device deviceFromOldList: oldDeviceList) {
    devicesToDelete.putIfAbsent(deviceFromOldList.id, deviceFromOldList);
}

// in case you need a Collection:
Collection<Device> allDevicesToDelete = devicesToDelete.values();
```

`putIfAbsent` will only store the mapping if the key is not already present. This will get you the performance of hashing while only considering the ID.

You may change the type argument `Object` in `Map<Object,Device>` to whatever type your ID has, though it doesn’t matter for the operation, if all you need at the end, is the `Collection<Device>`.

You can use a Stream, e.g.

```
Map<Object, Device> devicesToDelete = getCurrentDevices().stream()
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(
        deviceFromOldList -> deviceFromOldList.id, Function.identity(), (a,b) -> a));
```

though, it’s debatable whether this is a necessary change. The loop is not bad.